# Will relativistic glider cause lower gravitational force in Newtonian gravitation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, relativity

In the articles [The relativistic glider](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0612131) and [The relativistic glider revisited](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2298), the relativistic glider is proposed where a quasi-rigid body can slow down its fall under gravity without any reaction force, which is predicted by general relativity. So, when considering the glider in Newtonian sense, will the lower acceleration of the glider indicate that smaller gravitational force is being exerted on the glider? Does that mean that the reaction force on the planet will be smaller as well from Newton's Third Law of Motion?